# Dropdown box like google search box designed in css

Tags: php, css

Currently I am using normal CSS dropdown list and calling data from database through PHP. 
 But I want to create a search box like google.com has, wherein when you type, it will show suggestions from my database. I have its code in JQuery but I don’t know how to use it properly. Is it possible to create it using CSS and PHP?

Comment: If you want any help, you should try yourself, show your code and ask specificly for help. No one will design the code for you..

Comment: Soory Jan. I didn't mean that. I just wanted to know if that is possible. And if someone can tell me where to find the code that will be great. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Datalist

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
  <input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

and try your self, do some R & D. and if you find any problem then post @ stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks Siddharth. I really appreciate your help. Will try it and update here :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Siddharth. Its Working perfect.